# How to simplify this software architecture?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, architecture

I have a manager that mange the worker. And worker doing many work requests.

A Manager is a program that monitor all the workers, and communicated with the workers via TCP port. I created many thread to different workers, for example, a data collect workers, a separate thread for that to execute, is responsible for data collection. Only manager can communicate among with workers, and manager can check the workers status. All the work request must though the manager to assign the work request to the workers.

The Worker is a instance that running the while true loop, which open a TCP port that allow the manager to assign the work request to them. And each work request is assigned, a new thread will to assign to handle the work tasks. When the work request is done, the result will send back to the manager.

All the data communicate within the manager and the worker via a TCP Socket. All these are using java to implement. And the data will be a binary data.

But my question is , will it be too many thread or too complex in this architecture? For example:

User -> assign a work task -> Manager (Holding many threads, associated with workers) --->assign a work task to the workers ---> (Each work tasks may involve more than one worker, and more complex, which may be sync or async work tasks)--> if this is a sync work task involve two workers, two new threads will be opened, and execute.

As you can see, only one user request may involve 3+ threads. If there are many users, the threading number will be increased a lot. Or any suggestions to make it simpler? Thanks.

Comment: These systems/threads - are they distributed over many networked boxes?

Comment: It may or may not. When a worker is extremely high work load, it may use a separate server to run it.

Comment: Did you take a look at something like Akka (http://akka.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to consider the [thread pool pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) or notifying thread manager pattern because the problem you describe can be solved by smart management of thread pool of  constant size. However, you will need to apply few customizations to make it the best fit for your specific problem.